# Update a table field if a successful insert occurs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two sql server tables where the first table is updated using the second's table data.

I want if a field from `table B` is inserted in `table A` successfully to update a boolean field of `table B` that shows that insert was successful.

How do i do this?

Comment: Could do with a little more information...what do your tables look like?  Which column is updated?

Comment: suppose i have this two table : Table A 
  name nvarchar(10)
  Code int
  Descr nvarchar(100) 

  Table B 
 BName nvarchar
 Bcode int
 Bdeacr nvarchar(100)
 IsInserted bit ,,, i want if a row from table B inserted in Table A ,, IsInserted column updated to true else false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap both statements in a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO A (...) SELECT ... FROM B WHERE ...;
UPDATE B SET B.isinserted = 1 WHERE ...;
COMMIT;
```

That way, B will only be updated if the INSERT succeeded. Make sure that you use the same WHERE clause on both statements.